# Order of global variables changes performance in C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multithreading, opengl

I've got a multi-threaded piece of code (Windows), using pthread for the threading in C++.

I have 4 threads splitting a single job such that each job is accessing 1/4 of quite a large global array.

If I define the pointer to the array in global scope at particular points in my global scope declaration section I find that I can get a factor of 2 reduction in performance - it appears as though the order of my global declarations matters to my apps performance.

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Here are my results:

- Single thread = 0.07 seconds
- 4 threads = 0.02 seconds (when global pointer to the big array is at
  the start of the global declarations)
- 4 threads = 0.04 seconds (when the global pointer to the big array is
  in the middle of the global declarations)

In case it matters, the pointers I'm declaring in global scope are:

GLbyte* render_flag;
GLfloat* surface_primative;

And as rightly pointed out I should comment that the precision of these tests is very high, 2 significant figures they may be, but they are highly consistent.

Has anybody come across a performance difference based on the order of global declarations before?  Or does anybody have any idea why this might be happening in theory?

**ADDITIONAL:**

I have noticed (thanks to advice from SO) that the array pointer declarations for the arrays used by my threads are directly beside (in memory space) a few other variables which are also modified by the threads:

```
int number_of_tiles;        
int success_count_1;   ///Counters for successful searches
int success_count_2;
int success_count_3;
int success_count_4;

int offset;   

GLbyte* render_flag;   ///Pointer to array of render flags
GLfloat* surface_primative;   ///Pointer to surface primative array
```

If I include some padding between the pointers to the arrays and the counters my code runs quickly again:

```
int number_of_tiles;        
int success_count_1;   ///Counters for successful searches
int success_count_2;
int success_count_3;
int success_count_4;
int offset;

char padding[100];   

GLbyte* render_flag;   ///Pointer to array of render flags
GLfloat* surface_primative;   ///Pointer to surface primative array
```

Comment: Some code maybe? Which declarations are you talking about? Didn't you say there's just one big array?

Comment: A test involving 0.02 seconds with only one significant figure is not very convincing. Can't you set up a test that runs for at least 15-20 seconds and then use that as a benchmark? Also be sure you enable optimization obviously.

Comment: Well there are plenty of global declarations in my application unfortunately, because its convenient for some of my threading, but I've noticed this particular declaration for a pointer to (what will become) a huge array matters where it sits within the pack.  I've never encountered this before.  The global variables are pointers to OpenGL arrays.  I'll add it to my question.

Comment: The tests are highly consistent, a larger time frame would reduce chance for error/CPU noise, but I hope you'll do me the credit of trusting that the 2 sig fig value is reliable, because it is.  It runs with this countless times and varies by 0.001 between runs (unless the global scope declaration is moved of course).  So it isn't 'noise' essentially.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but "threads" and "performance changes when I move a variable declaration" makes a little man inside my head say "false sharing".

Comment: In what respect is the question not clear?

Comment: @SingleEntity It would be more clear if it had an example that can be tested and reasoned about. "middle of global declarations" doesn't really say much. Still, with this amount of information my first reaction is false sharing.

Comment: Yeah I agree it would make solving it easier, the problem was it is such a convoluted piece of code it wouldn't be easily presented in SO, this is why I didn't put it in.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @SingleEntity: Could you at least post the global declarations near the slow case? SO thrives on good questions that other's can learn from, not just brief answers.

Comment: I may have found something useful out, yes, I will modify my question with a couple of snippets of my global declarations.  Of course, I'm more than happy to try and make a question useful to all.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SingleEntity: Yes. False sharing it is. Having counters that update next to data read by many threads will induce that problem. Had you included that from the start, everyone would've been certain about that. If those 4 counters are updated by different threads, you should minimize the number of times you write, or separate them by at least 64 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Art suggests in a comment, I suppose you might end up with [False Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), i.e. that the data shares a cache-line and threads/cores can't work efficiently because of that.

You need to keep the data each thread writes to fairly (64 to 256 bytes or so) separated to get good efficiency when working with multiple threads.

How does your data access/write pattern look like for the pointers and data?

**Update**

I'm not an expert, but it could be that the 1/4 distance, modulo cache-line size, could have the threads interfering with each other. Cache associativiy tries to mitigate this, but still.

Another issue would be if data near those pointers is being updated constantly.

A good profiler, like Intel's VTune should help diagnosing that.

As for the behaviour, I'd excpect the data to get allocated on different addresses depending on how you re-order stuff. How does the data around your pointers look like?

I think mitigating this is done by allocating slightly more memory than you need and aligning the block on a suitable n-bytes boundary. If the issue is not the data, but the pointers, you could align them on 64-byte boundaries, or keep local copies of them in each thread.

Again, I know Intel (in their IPP library) has a specific STL allocator for helping with that, in part. Reading up on that should help you.

The article "[Avoiding and Identifying false sharing](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads)" is a start, with some addiional pointers (heh ;).

Comment: Thank you Macke, that is a truly useful answer.  The large array I speak of is a contiguous array, the 4 threads send a pointer to locations within that array 1/4 each through the block and modify 1/4 of that block each.  From what you have said, this is likely my issue, though why it happens only when the array declarations are defined at certain points in my global declarations section still puzzles me.  Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it could be that the 1/4 distance, modulo cache-line size, could have the threads interferring with each other. I've amended the answer with some more info and links. HIH.

Comment: Also, are you updating those pointers or only reading from them? Are you writing data near those pointers? (like if you have a global counter or mutex that is updated often, nearby..)

Comment: @SingleEntity What are the other "global declarations"? Are some of those global declarations variables that get written by the threads? That's when false sharing happens.